# how to display a jpeg image completely on main window in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have a gui application which accepts some commands from other application.

There is a scenario where gui will receive a command to display some jpeg image completely on the main window, overshadowing all of gui on the window and then again I need to clear that image with another command.

For this I will need to call a member function and need to do all this stuff there, but I don't know how can I display the image on main window from there.

can anybody please help me with that.

I have tried the below code.

```
void App::display_testpattern(QString path){

QPixmap imageObject(path);
imageObject = imageObject.scaled(300,300,Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio);
mylabel=new QLabel("",backup);
mylabel->setGeometry(QRect(0,0,300,300));
mylabel->setPixmap(imageObject);
```

}

and this works for me only when I call it from constructor. But I need to call it from some other slot and it does not work for me. any suggestions on this

Comment: Do you need information how to display an image over GUI controls?

Comment: Maybe you want to use one of the follwoing: [`QStackedLayout `](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QStackedLayout.html), [`QStackedWidget `](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QStackedWidget.html), [`QSplashScreen `](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QSplashScreen.html).

Comment: No actual code, neither the existing code nor an attempt to show an image. And that's despite this being a fairly straightforward task. Vote to close.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can do the way I mentioned at the end of my question. The problem was allocation of QLabel. we need to allocate QLabel in constructor and this will work fine.

Thanks